# Can't execute c++ opencv function from PHP

Tags: php, c++, opencv

I want to make my c++ program run within PHP. In program below I want to make sure first that the program can be executed

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv/cv.h"
#include "opencv/highgui.h"

using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
Mat  imgOk = imread("C:/xampp/htdocs/coba2/src.jpg", 1);
imwrite("res.jpg", imgOk);
printf("hello");
return 0;
}
```

I call it from

```
<?php
exec('bin\\Debug\\co.exe', $output);

print_r(array_values($output));

?>
```

And the result on the webpage was only

Array ( )

And the image wasn't saved

I have also tried `passthru()`, `system()`, `shell_exec()` but none of those work

when I try

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include "opencv/cv.h"
 #include "opencv/highgui.h"

using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
printf("hello");
return 0;
}
```

it works fine

Array ([0]=> hello )

Any solutions?

Comment: could you use full path of the file: "Mat  imgOk = imread("/var/www/src.jpg", 1);"

Answer (score -1):

Maybe copy the OpenCV DLLs to your bin\Debug directory? You can find them in the OpenCV install directory.